# Unable to install Nuget Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization, +1 other package

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I am trying to install this package (version 1.1.3), receiving this error:

> The change on C:\Projects\Software License
>   Management\Main\SoftwareLicenseManagement\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3.nupkg
>   cannot be undone because a file already exists at C:\Projects\Software
>   License
>   Management\Main\SoftwareLicenseManagement\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3.nupkg.
>   The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.

However, this is after I have removed the file specified. Visual Studio then prompts me to restart VS in order to finish removing it. Rinse and repeats and does not work.

This also happens with Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.

I've tried using Nugets command line uninstall/reinstall method and still not being removed.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose you're using TFS because of this line: `The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.`. This "bug" can happen when you have a pending change on a Nuget package file and didn't commit yet.

Try committing your work (if possible). Doing a rollback on the package files instead of committing might also work.